# Tengo un problema al querer usar after:: en css

Tags: html, css, html5

Mi intencion es querer meter el icono de Github usando after pero no me estaria funcionando, ya probe de varias maneras :(

Codigo html:

```
<section id="link-github">Let's work together...

     <ul>
       <li class="links">Github</li>
     </ul>


  </section>
```

Codigo css:

```
.links::after{

  content: url('/Descargas/github.png');


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto no funciona así. No puedes meter la imagen directamente como `content`. Tienes que meterla como `background-image` y ajustar el tamaño de la imagen y del `::after` para que se muestre como deseas.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```css
.links::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25231.png');
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section id="link-github">Let's work together...

  <ul>
    <li class="links">Github</li>
  </ul>


</section>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono a la perfeccion!